# What is the "correct" way to have a Spring MVC controller return an excel xslx spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I have come up with at least three different ways to handle this.

1) I could use a @ResponseBody and return a String exactly like I do for this csv:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "googleStoreReport", produces = "text/csv")
@ResponseBody
public String googleStoreReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {
    List<Store> stores = storeService.getActiveStores();
    List<SapStore> sapStores = sapStoreService.getAllSapStores();
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"Google_Places_Bulk_Store_Upload.csv\"");
    response.setContentType("text/csv");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
.... create file contents ....
    return sb.toString();
}
```

2) I could use a view as described here: (I will have to create my own version of the Spring AbstractExcelView) http://www.technicalkeeda.com/spring-tutorials/generate-excel-using-spring-mvc  The approach here is to have the controller return a ModelAndView object with a List of objects containing row data.  Then you have a View object that converts the List to a spreadsheet using Poi and writing the spreadsheet as a stream to the reponse object.

3) I could extend AbstractHttpMessageConverter using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter as a template.  Instead of a ModelAndView object I return the list.  The MessageConverter works the same way as the ViewResolver but works on a different part of the Request Lifecycle. (translates the List into a stream of spreadsheet data)

I am mostly down to which is recommended: Extending AbstractView or AbstractHttpMessageConverter.  I did find this nice post from three years ago http://java.dzone.com/articles/rest-spring but the author has the same problem I have.  To make matters more confusing, Spring MVC seems to use both approaches..

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered extending your 1st solution to include some other xml based api like Jasper reports so that you are decoupling your data from the view?

Answer (score 0):

Just talked this over with a coworker and came to a rule to guide my decision.  Message converters seem to be designed to take an object or collection of objects and apply one set of rules.  This formatting works well with Json or if you have a schema that can help the converter format XML.  Views on the other hand work great if you are putting out data that can have multiple strict formats that do not have a schema.  You create a base view class to handle Excel Spread Sheets in general.  Then the base class is extended for each individual spread sheet type.

This answers my specific issue.  I am sure I have not fully explored this issue and welcome any further input.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, I would use a message converter in output format is simple, and a view in other cases.

If the controller method always generate same output format (always CSV), as there is no need for a template to generate the CSV file, I would use a MessageConverter

On opposite side, if you wanted to generate an xlsx file, I'd rather use a view because a view can make use of a template.